# Flashmode and OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: mac, texshop

I have trouble installing Claus Gerhardt Flashmode on my new Mac (Mac mini + Lion 10.8.2).

I use TeXShop.

- Flashmode 7.0.2 does not work at all. (It worked fine with my old Mac, 10.6.8)
- Instead, Flashmode 6.1.0 works under 10.8.2.

By the way, the synchronisation on both Flashmode is lousy or inexistant.

My feeling is that Flashmode does not have enough time to refresh the `synctex.gz` file. It works (very approximatively) only when I go backward in the file. (But I must recognise that synchronisation is not precise -- and often inexistent -- under TeXShop; I am still crying about my old Textures synchronisation ...)

Any suggestion?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I have edited your post: I assume you meant "with my old Mac, 10.6.8", not "10.8.6", as the latter does not exist yet... If I was wrong, feel free to roll back my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest version of Flashmode (v. 7.1.4).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). You can always expand your answer to increase the value. In any case some moderator or user with high privileges will change it into a comment.

Comment: I agree with @texenthusiast, this post would use some more details, epsecially reasoninh why `v6.1.0` works, `v7.0.2` does not, but `v7.1.4` does again.

Comment: I assume this is some idiosyncratic problem of the original poster's setup. The versions 7.0.2 to the latest 7.1.7 worked well for me. Version 7 is completely different from version 6 and cannot be compared.